# Delete files with a length of x or more characters

Tags: bash

I'm reviewing for an exam and one of the questions is asking me to write a single command that will delete the files in a given directory that are at least 6 characters long.

Example:

> person@ubuntumachine:~$ ls

```
abc.txt, abcdef.txt, 123456.txt, helloworld.txt, rawr.txt
```

The command would delete the files "abcdef.txt", "12346.txt" and "helloworld.txt".

I'm aware the at the * would be used at some point but I'm not sure what to use to indicate 6 characters long...

Thank you <3

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Since the question can have 2 interpretations, both answers are given:

**1. To delete files with 6 or more characters in the FILE NAME:**

```
rm ??????*
```

*Explanation:*

- `??????`: The `?`'s are to be entered literally. Each `?` matches any single character. So here it means "match any 6 characters"
- `*`: The `*` wildcard matches zero or more characters
- Therefore it removes any file with 6 or more characters.

Alternatively:

```
find -type f -name "??????*" -delete
```

*Explanation:*

- `find`: invoke the find command
- `-type f`: find only files.
- `-name "??????*"`: match any file with at least 6 characters, same idea as above.
- `-delete`: delete any such files found.

**2. To delete files with 6 or more characters in its CONTENTS:**

```
find -type f -size +5c -delete
```

*Explanation*:

- `find`: invoke the find command
- `-type f`: find only files (not directories etc)
- `-size +5c`: find only files greater than 5 characters long. **Note:** recall that `EOF` (end of file) counts as a character in this case. If you'd like to exclude `EOF` from your counter, change it from 5 to 6.
- `-delete`: delete any such files found

Comment: Given the examples, I think the question is about length of filename, not the contents, but the title makes it sound like your answer is acceptable. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter good call, updated my answer for both interpretations.

Comment: Thank you, the first part is what I was looking for. I knew it was something extremely simple as question marks but I wasn't sure what character it was. :)

Comment: Wow, my solution was way too complicated.  Your rm solution is definitely a better answer.

Comment: @antik I actually thought about route you took to make the regex matching more dynamic - it'd easier to scale to new requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
$ ls|while read filename; do test ${#filename} -gt 6 && echo rm "$filename"; done
```

The trick is to use the `${#foo}` construct to get the length of the filename.

Once you're satisfied with the output, immediately run the following after the previous command:

```
$ !! | sh
```

This repeats the last command (which shows the rm command to delete the files) and pipe it to sh to really execute it.

Answer (score 0):

This will perform the requested logic on the current directory and all subdirectories.

`find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex ".*/[^/]{5}[^/]+$" -exec rm -vf {} \;`

- `find .`

  - searches the local directory (change the .
    to search elsewhere)
- `-type f`

  - considers files only
- `-regextype posix-egrep`

  - use egrep regex syntax (this is what I know)
- `-regex ".*/[^/]{5}[^/]+$"`

  - find will match all paths matching this regex
  - the regex deconstructs as follows:

    - `.*/` effectively ignores the path until the filename
    - `[^/]{5}` finds 5 characters that are not slashes
    - `[^/]+$`    requires at least one more character (thus: 6 or more) that is not a slash to appear before the end of line ($)
- `-exec rm -vf {} \;`

  - find will replace the `{}` with each file its search query matches (in this case, files with paths that match our regex).  Thus, this achieves the deletion.  `-vf` added to print the results so you know what's happened.

    - `-exec` is picky about syntax - the `\;` is necessary to avoid `find: missing argument to '-exec'` encountered if a simple `;` is used in its place.
    - You can test this by using `-print` instead of `-exec rm -vf {} \;` or simply removing the `-exec rm -vf {} \;` (`-print` is find's default behavior)